# Plone 4.3.3 - Schema-Driven types - plone.directives.form not importing

Tags: python, macos, plone, plone-4.x, zcml

I am following the Plone guide for Schema-Driven Types: http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/prerequisite.html

Running:

- Mac OSX 10.8.5 Mountain Lion
- Plone 4.3.3 http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/4.3.3

When I get to the second page on Testing the Type, I get an error.

I have the ZCML error below. I have already made sure to do what it says. I did another clean install and received the same error. Here is what it says in the guide.

---

If Zope doesn’t start up:

Look for error messages on the console, and make sure you start in the foreground with ./bin/instance fg. You could have a syntax error or a ZCML error.
If you have a failed import for plone.directives.form, make sure that you specified the [grok] extra for plone.app.dexterity in your setup.py install_requires.

---

Error Message:

```
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Users/Josh/Documents/Plone4/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.3-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 98.4-102.10

ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Users/Josh/Documents/Plone4/zinstance/src/example.conference/example/conference/configure.zcml", line 18.2-18.27

NameError: name 'form' is not defined
```

Here is the full log of the error message http://pastie.org/9200196

Comment: Add the content of `/Users/Josh/Documents/Plone4/zinstance/src/example.conference/example/conference/configure.zcml` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I did with the help of one of the amazing developers at where I work.

On the Setting the schema part of the guide, I did not fully change program.py & session.py.

The arguments change in IProgram to the following below:

class IProgram(model.Schema):

NOT: class IProgram(form.Schema, IImageScaleTraversable):

You must remove only what the guide tells you to remove.